# Small problem in attempt to find $3$ Pythagorean triples to make a right angle.

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic, pythagorean-triples

I $intuit$ that the sum of accute angles of $2$ dissimilar Pythagorean triples cannot be a right angle because the sine and cosine of every triple is unique. I wrote a program to see if some combination of $3$ triples would work and I seem to have found many but I wanted to verify the results manually and here is the problem
I found with $(3,4,5), (12,5,26), (63,16,65)$ where

$$\sin\alpha =\frac{4}{5}, \cos\alpha =\frac{3}{5}\quad \sin⁡\beta=\frac{5}{13}, \cos\beta=\frac{12}{13}\quad \sin\gamma=\frac{16}{65}, \cos\gamma=\frac{63}{65}$$
I've been given to understand that
$$\begin{align}
\sin(\alpha+\beta+\gamma) &= 
\sin\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma + \cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\gamma 
+\cos\alpha\cos\beta\sin\gamma - \sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma
\end{align}$$
Then I worked out the following in Word/Excel

[image]

I pasted the first $2$ $equals$ into excel and got $1$ for each.
Where did I go wrong in the last one?

Comment: The denominators in the third equations should be $65^3$, not 65.

Comment: Oh, oh ho!!!. I work nights; it's about my bedtime; I'm about brain dead and I see now $\frac{4225}{65^2}=1$.  The problem is solved. Thanks.